# Log4cxx: Hour based file rotation using appender

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, windows-10-desktop, log4cxx

I am able to build log4cxx with following apr, apr-util and libexpat versions using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 for both 32 bit and 64 bit(Disabled libiconv).
apr-1.7.0,
APR-util 1.6.1,
log4cxx-0.10.0 and
libexpat-R_2_2_10

To test whether builds are correct or not before using them on actual project, tried using them in simple console test application. Test code looks like below. I am not writing any log text to the file, just tried file rotation.

```
log4cxx::DailyRollingFileAppenderPtr debugRollingFileAppender1(new \
        log4cxx::DailyRollingFileAppender());

    //Create the date pattern in the folder structure.
    std::string aDatePattern = std::string("D:\\LogFolder\\Log4cxx_2019_Test\\") + "%Y%m%d\\%H\\" + "test" + ".log";

    LOG4CXX_DECODE_CHAR(aTempLogDatePattern, aDatePattern);
    debugRollingFileAppender1->setDatePattern(aTempLogDatePattern);

    log4cxx::helpers::Pool pool;

    log4cxx::PatternLayoutPtr debugLayout(new log4cxx::PatternLayout());
    debugLayout->setConversionPattern(LOG4CXX_STR("%d   [%t]    %5p %m%n"));

    debugRollingFileAppender1->setLayout(debugLayout);
    debugRollingFileAppender1->activateOptions(pool);

    LoggerPtr logger = Logger::getLogger(_T("LogInfo"));
    logger->addAppender(debugRollingFileAppender1);
    logger->setLevel(Level::getInfo());
```

Test application is building properly but this code is not creating new folder for every hour as specified in pattern. That is I am expecting it to create each new folder for every hour inside main folder of the current day.

Am I missing anything here? could you please help

Thanks

Comment: I believe that the rollover will not be triggered unless you're actually logging - have you tried logging messages to make sure that it does do the rollover?

Comment: @rm5248
Yes I had same doubt, now tried by writing log to file and started getting following exception.

VS output Windows displays below exception details at the time of rolling:
"Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8EC56A308 in Log4cxx_Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: log4cxx::helpers::IOException at memory location 0x000000D21274E200".

Console window displays below exception,
"log4cxx: Exception during rollover".

From code not able to handle this exception to see details.

Comment: Two things to try: 1. upgrade to 0.11.0 which was released a few weeks ago. 2. catch the exception and see what it says; my guess is that it doesn't have permissions or a directory doesn't exist.  If neither works, open an issue on the [Apache JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa) and I can help you more.

Comment: @rm5248, There is no permission issues, on application launch, folders and file are getting created properly and logging works, it fails only during roll over. I also tried launching application as admin, didn't work.

I tried debugging the issue, "handle = CreateFileW(wfname, oflags, sharemode, NULL, createflags, attributes, 0);" call inside "apr_file_open" is failing. Since file creation failing, 'handle' pointer is invalid("0xffffffffffffffff"). I think this Windows API has some issue or in code some FLAGS needs to be set differently.

This code is located at "apr\file_io\win32"

Comment: @rm5248, logged issue 'LOGCXX-513', Thanks...